# How can a neural network predict a policy vector of non-constant length?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I am reviewing how the [AlphaZero](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Esurag/posts/alphazero.html) works. In the article it is said that the neural network predicts a single value number $v$ and a policy vector $\pi$:

```
P[s], v = nnet.predict(s)
```

For one state $s_1$ there can be 3 different actions, whereas for another state $s_2$ there can be 4 different actions, etc. That means a neural network predicts either 4 or 5 different numbers depending on the input. **Question: what kind of neural network does that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy network can output a constant length vector the same size as the action space. Then you can simply mask out the invalid actions so that they aren't chosen.

Comment: But that seems very inneficient. E.g. in chess the ratio of all vs invalid moves would be like 1/5

Comment: it may seem so, but this is usually the most practical solution